# Roblox lua - Unable to cast to Dictionary

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a problem with my script:

```
local light1 = script.Parent.lampa.SpotLight
local light2 = script.Parent.lampa.SpotLight1
local rotating_part = script.Parent.lampa

local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local tInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 4)

script.Parent.szklo.Touched:Connect(function()
    local play = tweenService:Create(rotating_part, tInfo, rotating_part.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 90, 0))
end)
```

Error is in line 9 (local play), When I run the script and touch the object, I se an error "Unable to cast to Dictionary". I want this script to rotate a part 90 degrees 4 times, when script is running. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should probably read the docs here: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create that should really be your answer, the 3rd parameter for tweenService:Create() is in the incorrect data type and should be in a dictionary (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Table)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a `CFrame` as the third parameter for the `TweenService:Create` function, which is in fact wrong, because the docs clearly mention that you need to pass in a `table`, with its keys set to the name of the `Property` you want to tween and its corresponding value set to the desired value to tween to.

So here's a working version of your code.

```
local play = tweenService:Create(rotating_part, tInfo, {CFrame = rotating_part.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 90, 0)})
```

Where we pass in a table with a key `CFrame` (*the property we want to tween*) and its value set to the goal `CFrame` (*the value the corresponding property should tween to*).

Comment: thx a lot. I forgot about it. :D